# Using gprof on a multitask ADA source code, I get the analysis of only the main task

Tags: ada, gprof

I follow all the steps to instrumentalize, run and analyse the obtained output (gmon.out), but the text file obtained shows the analysis of the execution of the main task only.

I've read about similar problems in Linux OS but I'm running on Windows.

Has anyone experience something similar?

Comment: A better question would include those steps, and a minimal reproducer with 2 trivial tasks to show the problem.

Comment: I guess gprof doesn’t know about the Ada tasking runtime, and vice versa. Is `gmon.out` generated by some sort of `atexit()` call? Do Ada tasks call the gprof output generator when they exit? (probably not). Maybe the gprof output for each task goes to a separate file for that task?

Comment: @AAA Please add the “better question” content very soon as requested by user_1818839 above, lest the SO reviewers (who are not part of the [ada]-tag community) of new-user questions judge your question harshly (e.g., deleting it).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.